# Trying to open the exe file in javascript without ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using Prime faces form and the exe was being launched on button click through Javascript using ActiveX Object.This functionality was working fine in IE(Internet Explorer) but Edge is not supporting ActiveX Object.

Anybody know the alternate of it?

Earlier We have tried with ActiveXObject and was working fine.

Comment: If you want users to run an .exe file, put a link to that .exe file on your page with some wording instructing users to download and run it.  Clandestinely running an executable on a user’s computer is the ultimate security violation, so you cannot reasonably expect it to work anymore.

Comment: use tags in a right way

Answer (score 0):

Except VGR's solution, I think there's no programmatical way to open exe file in a modern browser. But if you're using Edge, you can open that page in IE mode. Edge IE mode [supports ActiveX controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality).

Edge IE mode is designed for organizations that still need IE 11 for backward compatibility with existing websites but also need a modern browser. If you're in an organization, you can configure [IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) to make that page always open in IE mode. Or you can just use [Edge settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list#enable-the-local-site-list-experience) to configure IE mode pages.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.